# Returning blank data in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

im passing a `array data` in my `ajax` to controller and use the data to the `queries` but when i already return the data it's blank when i `alert` it but in my `network` it have a data. Can someone help me about this?

[image]

routes:

```
Route::get('/member/page/press_release_email/view_send_email_press_release/sent_email', 'Member\Press_Release_Controller@pass_id');
```

ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "/member/page/press_release_email/view_send_email_press_release/sent_email",
             data: {ids:myArr},
             dataType:"json",
             success: function(data){
                alert(data)
             }
        });
```

controller:

```
public function pass_id(Request $req)
{
    $emails = Tbl_press_release_recipient::select('research_email_address')->whereIn('recipient_id', Request::input('ids'))->get();
    return json_encode($emails);

}
```

Comment: That screenshot seems to be the request, not the response, so that doesn't really tell us anything. Are you saying the `alert(data)` literally displays a blank alert?

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah, look at the picture below the network.

Comment: OK. But what does the Network tab show as the response? Is it an empty array? If your controller returned an empty array (`[]`) because your query didn't return any records then `alert(data)` would just be an empty alert.

Comment: Why is there a backslash following `"Member"` at `'Member\Press_Release_Controller@pass_id'`?

Comment: @nnnnnn it returned `empty array ([])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to select `research_email_address` with their `recipient_id` but your ids are currently strings (As seen in your network's tab screenshot.)

You need to fill `myArr` with the `recipient_id` data.